# Problems firing my event for dynamically link buttons in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, dynamic, linkbutton

I have problems with my dynamically link buttons in asp pages. I use them for making a custom paging for a grid view. The idea is that i want to display them 20 about 20. It is working for first 20. When i display them it's all right. Then i press next for displaying the next 20. When i press next, it displaying me, but if a press a button other than the initial 20, it is going me at the first 20.

My init page:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (this.Tag.Equals("Shareholder"))
    {   
        InitComponents(false);  
    }

    /// Must be done everytime the page loads.
    InitializeList();

    if (!IsPostBack)
        InitializeUI();
}
```

Init link buttons

```
private void InitComponents(Boolean Prev)
{
        PanelPager.Controls.Clear();
        int nrInregistrari = Convert.ToInt32(DAActionar.CountActionari(11, LastBtnIndex));
        if (Prev == true)
        {
            LinkButton lnkPrev = new LinkButton();
            lnkPrev.Text = "Prev";
            PanelPager.Controls.Add(lnkPrev);
        }

        int BtnDeAfisat = 0;
        if (nrInregistrari > BTN_PER_SERIE * PAGE_SIZE)
        {
            BtnDeAfisat = BTN_PER_SERIE;
        }
        else
            BtnDeAfisat = nrInregistrari / PAGE_SIZE + 1;

        for (int index = 1; index <= BtnDeAfisat; index++)
        {
            int pageNo = index + LastBtnIndex;
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(PageChange);
            lnk.ID = "PageLink" + pageNo.ToString();
            lnk.CommandName = "Page";
            lnk.Text = " " + pageNo.ToString() + " ";
            lnk.CommandArgument = index.ToString();

            PanelPager.Controls.Add(lnk);

        }

        LinkButton lnkNext = new LinkButton();
        lnkNext.Click += new EventHandler(NextPage);
        lnkNext.Text = "Next";
        PanelPager.Controls.Add(lnkNext);
        LastBtnIndex += BtnDeAfisat;


}
```

event for next buttons

```
 private void NextPage(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
     InitComponents(true);
 }
```

PageChange:

```
  public void PageChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument) + 1;
            object dataSource = GetDataSource(OwnerId, null, pageIndex);
            PushData(dataSource);

        }
```

Comment: "Then i press next for displaying the next 20. When i press next, it displaying me, but if a press a button other than the initial 20, it is going me at the first 20." Could not understand issue you are facing. Can you be more descriptive. What shold happend when you click "button other than initial 20" ? Does it mean than you are not able to go forward after you reach 2nd 20 page number ?

Comment: Can you share the code of PageChange method?

Comment: @Chetan edit, the idea is that first 20 buttons which are initialize in init are working right, others does not fire event handler

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? When you click on the buttons other than initial buttons, is it executing PageChange method? If yes then what pageIndex you are getting there? Also check if NextPage method executes, if yes then what is the value populated in "nrInregistrari " ?

Comment: @Chetan, bro when i click on the buttons other than initial, NextPage is not working, it is not going there, only make a page reinit and displays me first 20 buttons

Comment: Are you using asp:dataPager or asp:panel?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET only the controls which are added as part of Page_Load will have their events attached and will be executed. Also in when a server side event is executed the page posts itself back and during that the page_load executes first and then the event handler code gets executed.

So your first set of button events executed coz they were attached to event as part of page_load. Now during event of those button you are calling InitComponents method. So as I explained during the event page_load happens first which calls InitComponents method, which adds button to panel but InitComponents method executes again as part of event handler code which removes controls from Panel and re-creates them and add them again to the Panel.

Now since controls created during 2nd execution of InitComponents method are not no part of page_load flow events attached to them are not firing when you click on them. It just posts back the page which executed InitComponents again and which creates new controls in the panel and they will have their events working fine because they are created as part of page_load flow.

Pardon me if it confuses you.

Now the solution to this would be to use a control which can create many buttons automatically for you based on the number of items and also fires events all the times.

I do not have anything working right now for you. I found this article with working sample code which you can consider as an example and implement in your work.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-DataList-control-in-ASPNet.aspx

The example explains how to display page numbers and also how to bind your data based on the selected page number.